# How to get quality results from gitlab autodevops

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I'm testing Gitlab AutoDevOps with my project. My problem is that AutoDevOps do a quality check, it passes, but I don't know where to find the result, is says it upload an artifact, but doesn't say where.

Here are the logs:

```
$ # Auto DevOps variables and functions # collapsed multi-line command
$ setup_docker
$ code_quality
Unable to find image 'registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/codequality:11-8-stable' locally
11-8-stable: Pulling from gitlab-org/security-products/codequality
911c6d0c7995: Pulling fs layer
aff9b9c51076: Pulling fs layer
9500841639b7: Pulling fs layer
ce7d9f10a155: Pulling fs layer
0348d20deefe: Pulling fs layer
1349cf012439: Pulling fs layer
80d35bc2fcb0: Pulling fs layer
32785dd38a36: Pulling fs layer
5b14ec8e4612: Pulling fs layer
ce7d9f10a155: Waiting
0348d20deefe: Waiting
1349cf012439: Waiting
80d35bc2fcb0: Waiting
32785dd38a36: Waiting
5b14ec8e4612: Waiting
911c6d0c7995: Verifying Checksum
911c6d0c7995: Download complete
9500841639b7: Verifying Checksum
9500841639b7: Download complete
aff9b9c51076: Verifying Checksum
aff9b9c51076: Download complete
1349cf012439: Verifying Checksum
1349cf012439: Download complete
0348d20deefe: Verifying Checksum
0348d20deefe: Download complete
80d35bc2fcb0: Verifying Checksum
80d35bc2fcb0: Download complete
ce7d9f10a155: Verifying Checksum
ce7d9f10a155: Download complete
32785dd38a36: Verifying Checksum
32785dd38a36: Download complete
5b14ec8e4612: Verifying Checksum
5b14ec8e4612: Download complete
911c6d0c7995: Pull complete
aff9b9c51076: Pull complete
9500841639b7: Pull complete
ce7d9f10a155: Pull complete
0348d20deefe: Pull complete
1349cf012439: Pull complete
80d35bc2fcb0: Pull complete
32785dd38a36: Pull complete
5b14ec8e4612: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:140e9a52a1700dae0aef504b3daf9854de98588ac6a9e733c0fe6938f65220ad
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/codequality:11-8-stable
Unable to find image 'codeclimate/codeclimate:0.72.0' locally
0.72.0: Pulling from codeclimate/codeclimate
2f3f3e5e133b: Pulling fs layer
2654c654a6e7: Pulling fs layer
412e64056adf: Pulling fs layer
a3ed95caeb02: Pulling fs layer
b34d109380af: Pulling fs layer
ef84039c747a: Pulling fs layer
0b64161d56c4: Pulling fs layer
532d14be51e6: Pulling fs layer
8210184098e2: Pulling fs layer
bd15a272ee53: Pulling fs layer
d25d7915b947: Pulling fs layer
4e198ced2ee0: Pulling fs layer
5bcf14160dfc: Pulling fs layer
f47a75dcba39: Pulling fs layer
a3ed95caeb02: Waiting
b34d109380af: Waiting
ef84039c747a: Waiting
0b64161d56c4: Waiting
532d14be51e6: Waiting
8210184098e2: Waiting
bd15a272ee53: Waiting
d25d7915b947: Waiting
4e198ced2ee0: Waiting
5bcf14160dfc: Waiting
f47a75dcba39: Waiting
412e64056adf: Verifying Checksum
412e64056adf: Download complete
2f3f3e5e133b: Verifying Checksum
2f3f3e5e133b: Download complete
2654c654a6e7: Verifying Checksum
2654c654a6e7: Download complete
a3ed95caeb02: Verifying Checksum
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete
b34d109380af: Verifying Checksum
b34d109380af: Download complete
ef84039c747a: Verifying Checksum
ef84039c747a: Download complete
2f3f3e5e133b: Pull complete
0b64161d56c4: Verifying Checksum
0b64161d56c4: Download complete
532d14be51e6: Verifying Checksum
532d14be51e6: Download complete
8210184098e2: Verifying Checksum
8210184098e2: Download complete
bd15a272ee53: Verifying Checksum
bd15a272ee53: Download complete
4e198ced2ee0: Verifying Checksum
4e198ced2ee0: Download complete
d25d7915b947: Verifying Checksum
d25d7915b947: Download complete
f47a75dcba39: Verifying Checksum
f47a75dcba39: Download complete
5bcf14160dfc: Verifying Checksum
5bcf14160dfc: Download complete
2654c654a6e7: Pull complete
412e64056adf: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
b34d109380af: Pull complete
ef84039c747a: Pull complete
0b64161d56c4: Pull complete
532d14be51e6: Pull complete
8210184098e2: Pull complete
bd15a272ee53: Pull complete
d25d7915b947: Pull complete
4e198ced2ee0: Pull complete
5bcf14160dfc: Pull complete
f47a75dcba39: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c8afb8c2037f7b9c5c9ae198aff00b1cf80db11d3591fbe89dfb3c69192663f1
Status: Downloaded newer image for codeclimate/codeclimate:0.72.0
WARNING: A new version (v0.83.0) is available. Upgrade instructions are available at: https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate#packages
Uploading artifacts...
gl-code-quality-report.json: found 1 matching files 
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=165987129 responseStatus=201 Created token=4_FrYtaJ
Job succeeded
```

Where can I find the results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the answer was quite easy, gitlab uploaded it to the gitlab registry.

You can go to your-project > Registry, and then you will see a group/subgroup/project/autodevops element. Copy the link, and then you will be able to run the container

First you have to login:

```
docker login gitlab.com # if you use cloud version
```

Then

```
docker run --rm -it  registry.gitlab.com/group/subgroup/project/autodevops:<tag>
```

You can also see what is doing the autoDevOps script here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml

You can also download the file from UI in Jobs Screen.

If you are in free version, you will not be able to get it integrated to UI